# Docusign Custom button throws Invalid email address error for correct email

Tags: docusignapi

I have a custom button in Salesforce that has the javascript code to generate the docusign parameter with template id and recipient list CRL. And using demo docusign account for testing purpose. Here, am using docusign **Salesforce Connect** and not API.

Eventhough my email address is correct, when I click on the docusign custom button, I am getting an error message as follows,

> **Error:** Incorrect email address format. Verify the email address or
>   contact your administrator for the correct format

But the docusign param generated values are correct for the email address,

```
 https://dsfs.cs62.visual.force.com/apex/DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?
    CES=Medical+Release+Form.pdf&
    RES=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0&
    DST=E1377257-80EB-4F3D-A046-A1D033CBD4F5&
    DSEID=0&
    LA=0&
    SourceID=5005C000000UNG1&
    CEM=Please+sign+the+forms+given&
    OCO=Send&
    CRL=Email~+kamatchidevi%40mstsolutions.com%3BLastName~+test+doc+%3BRole~Signer1
```

***Thanks & Regards,***

***Kamatchi Devi***

Answer (score 2):

The + signs are causing the issue here, there is also no need to encode it yourself as it's done by the manage package into the URL. However, if you are going to URL encode I would recommend doing the entire string, like so

> CRL = encodeURIComponent('Email~kamatchidevi@mstsolutions.com;LastName~test doc;Role~Signer1')